# JavaScript-Random Greek Letters Not Working

Tags: javascript

So I have this absolutely fantastic javascript random stuff generator, except for one thing.  You see, I have it set so that if it brings up a certain random value, it throws in a Greek letter too.  It worked great until I worked on it some and now that part is broken.  The rest of it works, but that one part is necessary for it to make sense to those using it.  Here is the code:

```
<div id="unitInfo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pre = ["Research", "Storage", "Containment", "Mobile", "Biological", "Armed",     "Dimensional", "Reliquary"];
var types = ["Command", "Site", "Sector", "Area", "Unit", "Task Force"];
var greek = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Zeta", "Eta", "Theta",     "Iota", "Kappa", "Lambda", "Mu", "Nu", "Xi", "Omicron", "Pi", "Rho", "Sigma", "Tau",     "Upsilon", "Phi", "Chi", "Psi", "Omega"];
var update = ["online", "offline", "classified", "under repair", "experiencing     containment breach", "under attack", "[CONNECTION SEVERED]", "[DATA EXPUNGED]",     "terminated", "rogue", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure",     "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure",     "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure",     "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure", "secure",     "secure", "secure", "secure"];

var info = pre[Math.floor(Math.random() * pre.length)];
    info += " " + types[Math.floor(Math.random() * types.length)];
if ( types == "Task Force" )
{
    info += " " + greek[Math.floor(Math.random() * greek.length)];
    info += "-" + ( 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) );
    info += " is " + update[Math.floor(Math.random() * update.length)];
}
else
{
    info += "-" + ( 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) );
    info += " is " + update[Math.floor(Math.random() * update.length)];
}
document.getElementById("unitInfo").innerHTML = info;
</script>
```

Comment: Why so many `secure, secure...`? That reduces probability on the other items.

Comment: Exactly, I want it to turn up secure most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The `info` picks from `pre` and hence can never be `"Task force"`, so the `info += greek[...]` part of the `if` branch is never triggered.

---

May be this is what you want -

```
var info = types[Math.floor(Math.random() * types.length)];

if ( info == "Task Force" )
{
    info = pre[Math.floor(Math.random() * pre.length)] + " " + info;
    info += " " + greek[Math.floor(Math.random() * greek.length)];
    info += "-" + ( 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) );
    info += " is " + update[Math.floor(Math.random() * update.length)];
}
else
{
    info = pre[Math.floor(Math.random() * pre.length)] + " " + info;
    info += "-" + ( 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) );
    info += " is " + update[Math.floor(Math.random() * update.length)];
}
```

---

PS. Very cool selection of words.

Comment: Okay, so what now?  I tweaked the code (I edited the initial post above) but it continues to do the same thing.